# Finding cumulative occurrence of articles in orders

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SLQserver 2014, I have a table with sales (orders and articles) with an article appearing not more than once per order.

SALES

```
ORDER    ARTICLE
----------------
0001          A
0001          B
0001          C
0002          A
0002          C
0003          D
0004          A
```

I would like to know, sorted by articles being sold the most, in how many orders they have appeared.

Sorting by the times an article appears:

```
ARTICLE  COUNT
--------------
A         3
C         2
B         1
D         1
```

An there are a total of 4 order (0001, 0002, 0003, 0004)

The expected output would be something like:

```
ARTICLE  CUMULATIVE_ORDER_COUNT
-------------------------------
A         3
C         3
B         3
D         4
```

So, article A appears in 3 orders, when you add article C, they appear combined in 3 orders (article C does not appear in any different order then A), when you add article B, they still appear only in 3 orders, and finally, adding article D, they appear in 4 different orders.

I belive I need to do some kind of recursive query but I am struggling with the code.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: B and D have same number of occurrences so both 3,3,3,4 and 3,3,4,4 should be acceptable, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is rather complicated.  The idea is to assign each `order` a number which is the minimum "row" where it appears in the final output.

This is a little harder than I first thought.  It seems to require calculating the result set, applying the information to the orders, and then re-aggregating:

```
with t as (
      select v.*
      from (values ('0001', 'A'),
                   ('0001', 'B'),
                   ('0001', 'C'),
                   ('0002', 'A'),
                   ('0002', 'C'),
                   ('0003', 'D'),
                   ('0004', 'A')
            ) v(orderid, article)
     ),
     a as (
      select article, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (order by count(*) desc, article) as seqnum
      from t
      group by article
     ),
     aa as (
      select t.*, a.seqnum, min(seqnum) over (partition by orderid) as order_seqnum
      from t join
           a
           on t.article = a.article
     )
select article, count(*) as cnt,
       sum(sum(case when order_seqnum = seqnum then 1 else 0 end)) over (order by count(*) desc, article)
from aa
group by article;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c363f6b7c8ffdf6050550f3f9c965f1f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I think it is not the right answer. The query should do a recursive inner join of the nth first articles and count the number of distinct orders in which they appear. In my example, article A appears in 0001, 0002 and 0004 (3 orders), adding article C, both article A and C appear in order 0001, 0002 and 0004 (3 orders) and so on...

Comment: @OBT . . . I have fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery to find all articles that are ranked lower than an article (based on count and name) and perform a distinct count:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE([order] VARCHAR(10), article VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('0001', 'A'),
('0001', 'B'),
('0001', 'C'),
('0002', 'A'),
('0002', 'C'),
('0003', 'D'),
('0004', 'A');

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT article, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, article) AS rn
    FROM @t
    GROUP BY article
)
SELECT *, (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [order])
    FROM @t
    WHERE article IN (
        SELECT article
        FROM cte AS x
        WHERE rn <= cte.rn
    )
) AS running_order_count
FROM cte
ORDER BY rn
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with 
--  sample data
SALES as
(
    select  [ORDER] = '0001', [ARTICLE] = 'A' union all
    select  [ORDER] = '0001', [ARTICLE] = 'B' union all
    select  [ORDER] = '0001', [ARTICLE] = 'C' union all
    select  [ORDER] = '0002', [ARTICLE] = 'A' union all
    select  [ORDER] = '0002', [ARTICLE] = 'C' union all
    select  [ORDER] = '0003', [ARTICLE] = 'D' union all
    select  [ORDER] = '0004', [ARTICLE] = 'A'
),
--  find count by article + assign a row number
cte as
(
    select  [ARTICLE], [COUNT] = count(*), RN = row_number() over (order by count(*) desc, [ARTICLE])
    from    SALES s
    group by [ARTICLE]
)
select  *
from    cte c
        cross apply
        (
            -- for each row find the distinct [ORDER] for current [ARTICLE]
            -- including all earlier row. Based on `RN`
            select  CUMULATIVE_ORDER_COUNT  = count(distinct [ORDER])
            from    cte x
                    inner join SALES s  on  x.ARTICLE   = s.ARTICLE
            where   x.RN    <= c.RN
        ) cc
order by c.[COUNT] desc, c.[ARTICLE]

/*  RESULT

ARTICLE COUNT   RN  CUMULATIVE_ORDER_COUNT
A       3       1   3
C       2       2   3
B       1       3   3
D       1       4   4

*/
```